# Update statement not working getting error ORA-01031: Insufficient privileges

Tags: sql, oracle

My update table query not working. if i am runing this query as a sub part it's working but as soon as i am runing as a whole it giving me exception  ORA-01031: Insufficient privileges.

```
 declare
         var_sqlString varchar2(2500);
         begin    
    var_sqlString :='UPDATE (select ''A''||registration_id from sde.table_registry where table_name=''OPENPOINT'' and OWNER=''EDGIS'') 
    SET OPERATINGVOLTAGE=''21'' where GLOBALID=''{3B5C4257-12D8-4CA9-82E4-427AC9D79BB0}''' ;
    dbms_output.put_line(var_sqlString); 
          EXECUTE immediate var_sqlString;
          commit;        
         end;
```

When i am executing this query `dbms_output.put_line` giving me bellow result.

```
UPDATE (select 'A'||registration_id from sde.table_registry where table_name='OPENPOINT' and OWNER='EDGIS') 
SET OPERATINGVOLTAGE='21' where GLOBALID='{3B5C4257-12D8-4CA9-82E4-427AC9D79BB0}'
```

And when i am runing the above query than also i am getting the same error. Now the problem is when i am executing part one which is: `select 'A'||registration_id from sde.table_registry where table_name='OPENPOINT' and OWNER='EDGIS'`
Its giving me the result  which is `A126` and then i am passing that result in my update statement, the update statement works fine. But as a whole is not working .....???

Comment: What schema owns the anticipated result, 'A126'? Is it the sames as the user executing this anonymous block?

Comment: You most likely do not have update privileges. In oracle there is a way to give yourself privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the solution, Problem was Oracle was treating table retrieval statement as a whole staring not a table, So that was the cause of my problem. So i added select statement at the beginning of my query and got the output.
So updated query would be

```
set serveroutput on
declare
     var_sqlString varchar2(2500);
     begin

select 'UPDATE edgis.' || 
(select 'A'||registration_id from sde.table_registry where table_name='OPENPOINT' and OWNER='EDGIS') 
|| ' SET OPERATINGVOLTAGE=''21'' where GLOBALID=''{3B5C4257-12D8-4CA9-82E4-427AC9D79BB0}'''  into var_sqlString from dual;
dbms_output.put_line(var_sqlString);  
      EXECUTE immediate var_sqlString;
     commit;  
     end;
```

Thanks! For helping me but i found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The error `Insufficient privileges` tells you that you are not allowed to do an `UPDATE` statement on this table.

Check the user rights on the user you are using for this query. You should grant `UPDATE` privileges for the user you are using.

You can read the Oracle documentation on [how to manage user privileges](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96521/privs.htm).

Comment: I have all access right this querry is working when i am doing like. select ''A''||registration_id from sde.table_registry where table_name=''OPENPOINT'' and OWNER=''EDGIS''  than UPDATE table_name
SET OPERATINGVOLTAGE='21' where GLOBALID='{3B5C4257-12D8-4CA9-82E4-427AC9D79BB0}'

Comment: @BhaskarSingh maybe this post could help you : http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01031_insufficient_privileges.htm

Comment: @BhaskarSingh The SELECT query is working but is this UPDATE query working ? (UPDATE table_name SET OPERATINGVOLTAGE='21' where GLOBALID='{3B5C4257-12D8-4CA9-82E4-427AC9D79BB0}' )

Comment: I think i dont have any  privileges issue as i do have all  privileges. I executed this query in parts and is working, but i dont know why is's not working as whole in oracle.....

Comment: @BhaskarSingh No idea why you can get it to work when the query is in parts (are you in the same environment ?), but you CLEARLY have privileges issues. As the exception tells you : Insufficient privileges, it cannot be clearer ;-)